# How to select network interface given ip address in ansible across Debian and FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, ansible, jinja, jinja2

I'm looking for an expression to fetch the interface name given an ip address assigned to that iface, across Linux and FreeBSD.

This question is based on this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/948288/416946

This jinja2 expression will, on Debian, return the interface object (from ansible facts) for the `given_ip`

```
iface_for_ip: >-
  {{ ansible_facts
  | dict2items
  | selectattr('value.ipv4', 'defined')
  | selectattr('value.ipv4.address', 'equalto', given_ip)
  | first  }}
```

However this does not work on FreeBSD because the `ipv4` structure is an array, not an object.

If you run just this snippet:

```
iface_for_ip: >-
  {{ ansible_facts
  | dict2items
  | selectattr('value.ipv4', 'defined') }}
```

You will get an output like this:

on Debian

```
  - key: eth0
    value:
      active: true
      device: eth0
      ipv4:
        address: 10.8.20.206
        broadcast: 10.8.20.255
        netmask: 255.255.255.0
        network: 10.8.20.0
      ipv6:
      - address: fe80::84ee:35ff:fed4:a23c
        prefix: '64'
        scope: link
      macaddress: 00:ee:35:00:00:00
      mtu: 1500
      promisc: false
      speed: 10000
      type: ether
```

on FreeBSD

```
  - key: epair0b
    value:
      device: epair0b
      flags:
      - UP
      - BROADCAST
      - RUNNING
      - SIMPLEX
      - MULTICAST
      ipv4:
      - address: 10.8.20.207
        broadcast: 10.8.20.255
        netmask: 255.255.255.0
        network: 10.8.20.0
      ipv6: []
      macaddress: 00:ee:23:00:00:00
      media: Ethernet
      media_options:
      - full-duplex
      media_select: 10Gbase-T
      media_type: 10Gbase-T
      metric: '0'
      mtu: '1500'
      options:
      - PERFORMNUD
      status: active
      type: ether
```

**How can I use a jinja2 ansible expression to fetch the interface given just the ip address cross platform?** `json_query` could be useful here, but the method eludes me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference in data collected by [setup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#ansible-builtin-setup-gathers-facts-about-remote-hosts) on Debian and FreeBSD.

---

In Ubuntu (Debian derivative) the attribute *ipv4* is a dictionary. Secondary addresses are stored in the list *ipv4_secondaries*. As a first step create a list of devices and ipv4 addresses. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: ansible_facts.distribution
    - set_fact:
        ifc_list: "{{ ansible_facts|
                      dict2items|
                      json_query(query)|
                      selectattr('ipv4')|list }}"
      vars:
        query: "[?value.type == 'ether'].{device: value.device,
                                          ipv4: value.ipv4.address}"
    - debug:
        var: ifc_list
```

give (abridged)

```yaml
  ansible_facts.distribution: Ubuntu

  ifc_list:
  - device: eth0
    ipv4: 10.1.0.27
```

Then *"select network interface for given ip address"*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        iface_for_ip: "{{ ifc_list|
                          selectattr('ipv4', 'eq', ip_address)|
                          map(attribute='device')|list }}"
      vars:
        ip_address: "10.1.0.27"
    - debug:
        var: iface_for_ip
```

give (abridged)

```yaml
  iface_for_ip:
  - eth0
```

---

In FreeBSD the attribute *ipv4* is a list. Create a list of devices and ipv4

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: ansible_facts.distribution
    - set_fact:
        ifc_list: "{{ ansible_facts|
                      dict2items|
                      json_query(query)|
                      selectattr('ipv4')|list }}"
      vars:
        query: "[?value.type == 'ether'].{device: value.device,
                                          ipv4: value.ipv4[].address}"
    - debug:
        var: ifc_list
```

give (abridged)

```yaml
  ansible_facts.distribution: FreeBSD

  ifc_list:
  - device: wlan0
    ipv4:
    - 10.1.0.51
```

Then *"select network interface for given ip address"*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        iface_for_ip: "{{ iface_for_ip|default([]) + [item.device] }}"
      loop: "{{ ifc_list }}"
      when: ip_address in item.ipv4
      vars:
        ip_address: "10.1.0.51"
    - debug:
        var: iface_for_ip
```

give (abridged)

```yaml
  iface_for_ip:
  - wlan0
```

Since Ansible 2.8 you can use test [*contains*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-if-a-list-contains-a-value). The task below gives the same results

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        iface_for_ip: "{{ ifc_list|
                          selectattr('ipv4', 'contains', ip_address)|
                          map(attribute='device')|
                          unique }}"
      vars:
        ip_address: "10.1.0.51"
```

---

Q: **"*How to remove the final set_fact + loop so it can be defined purely in a vars file?*"**

A: The attribute *ipv4* is a list. To use *selectattr*, instead of a *loop*, you'll need a [test](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#list-of-builtin-tests) *contains(seq, value)*. There is no such test in Ansible version 2.7 and lower. Only [*in(value, seq)*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#in) test with reversed order of parameters is available. If you don't have Ansible version 2.8 or higher you'll have to write your own test. For example

```python
shell> cat test_plugins/contains.py 

def contains(l, value):
    return value in l


class TestModule:
    """Main test class from Ansible."""

    def tests(self):
        """Add these tests to the list of tests available to Ansible."""
        return {
            'contains': contains
        }
```

Then the *set_fact* gives the same result. The expression can be also used in *vars*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        iface_for_ip: "{{ ifc_list|
                          selectattr('ipv4', 'contains', ip_address)|
                          map(attribute='device')|list }}"
```

Comment: This seems like a bug. It ought to be a list on every OS.

Comment: Yes. You're probably [right](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+ipv4.secondaries).

Comment: Many thanks @VladimirBotka that's some great jmespath talent. I've condensed it so it can almost be run as pure vars ([see here](https://gist.github.com/Ramblurr/5d8324e0154ea6be52407618222fcaf7)) Any idea how to remove the final set_fact + loop so it can be defined purely in a vars file?

Comment: You're welcome. Write a custom test. I've added an example.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired from the other answer and [the gist linked there](https://gist.github.com/Ramblurr/5d8324e0154ea6be52407618222fcaf7)

```yaml
vars:
    freebsd_query: "[*].{device: device, active: active, ipv6: ipv6, ipv4: ipv4[? address == '{{ ip_find_iface }}']}[?ipv4])" # string must be in ' # sorry, only partial interface info, did not find out how to return all info directly
    linux_query: "[?ipv4.address == '{{ ip_find_iface }}']" # string must be in '
    ipv6_query: "[*].{device: device, active: active, ipv4: ipv4, ipv6: ipv6[? address == '{{ ip_find_iface }}']}[?ipv6]" # string must be in ' # sorry, only partial info, did not find how to return the full one
    ip_query: "{{ ip_find_iface | ipv6 | ternary(
        ipv6_query,
        ansible_facts[ansible_facts.interfaces | first].ipv4 is mapping | ternary(linux_query, freebsd_query)
    ) }}.device"
    all_interfaces: "{{ ansible_facts.interfaces | map('extract', ansible_facts) }}"
    iface_for_ip: "{{ all_interfaces | json_query(ip_query) }}"
```

`ip_query` first checks if the ip is in ipv6 format. If not, it checks if `{anyNetwork}.ipv4` is a dict. The query for `json_query()` is selected depending on this.

(there may be typos, since I can not (simply) test all. already corrected about 5 times...)
(how this developped: https://gist.github.com/Ramblurr/5d8324e0154ea6be52407618222fcaf7)